# Large C++ array causes segmentation fault on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, segmentation-fault, clang

I’m building an iOS app using C++ and encountered an issue with a large array. The problem is that if the array reaches a certain size I’m getting an exception of type EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV), subtype KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE, with a segmentation fault (11) termination signal.

The interesting aspect is that I’m getting that exception regardless of whether I place the array on the stack or on the heap.

The code putting the array on the stack looks as follows:

```
class Model
{
public:
  Model() { };

private:
  static constexpr std::size_t VERTEX_COUNT =  25894;

  Vertex _vertices[VERTEX_COUNT] =
  {
    { { 46.629387f, 647.478271f,  58.987785f }, {  0.140482f, 0.716024f, 0.683795f }, false },
    { { 86.409439f, 639.203247f,  57.095085f }, {  0.273239f, 0.689217f, 0.671059f }, false },
    { { 94.825722f, 586.618164f,  91.772812f }, {  0.375726f, 0.404750f, 0.833671f }, false },
    { { 50.570183f, 586.068481f, 100.536209f }, { -0.003906f, 0.451161f, 0.892434f }, false },
    // 25894 array entries in total
  };

  // all the rest
}
```

The struct used to populate the array looks as follows:

```
struct Vertex
{
  Vertex()
  {
  }

  Vertex(glm::vec3 coords, glm::vec3 norm, bool selected) :
    coordinates(coords),
    normal(norm),
    isSelected(selected)
  {
  }

  glm::vec3 coordinates;
  glm::vec3 normal;
  bool      isSelected;
};
```

The above code crashes on iOS 11.4 as soon as an instance of Model gets instantiated.

Now, this happens even if I change the line

```
Vertex _vertices[VERTEX_COUNT] =
```

to (allocating memory on the heap)

```
Vertex* _vertices = new Vertex[VERTEX_COUNT]
```

or to

```
std::unique_ptr<Vertex[]> _vertices = std::unique_ptr<Vertex[]>(new Vertex[VERTEX_COUNT]
```

or move the entire array definition into the constructor of `Model`.

The only way I could make it work so far is to change

```
Vertex _vertices[VERTEX_COUNT] =
```

to

```
static constexpr Vertex _vertices[VERTEX_COUNT] =
```

and add a corresponding constexpr constructor to the `Vertex` struct. However, I need to be able to edit the array at runtime and hence cannot declare it to be `static constexpr`.

Does anyone have some insight what might be going on here?

Comment: Sounds like you are creating multiple instances of `Model` and thus very quickly running out of memory. the `static` `_vertices` member makes it so there's only 1 large array instead of N

Comment: Doesn't it work if you remove `constexpr` and initialize it outside the class?

Comment: @AndyG: I hit the problem even if I only create a single instance of `Model`. As soon as this instance is being created, the problem strikes.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Do you mean making the array just static?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking. How big (in bytes) does that array get? 621456-828608 bytes something? Can you do `new char[828608];` or `char a[828608]; without problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create array by `new` without the initialization of its elements. When you create array onto heap with initialization, compiler needs to prepare enough room onto stack to call ctors for several objects of your array.

Look at the example below (it illustrates that the creation of dynamic array with initialization is dangerous):

```
struct vertex {
    float x,y,z;
    vertex() {}
    vertex(double x,double y,double z){}
};

int main() {
    vertex* v = new vertex[3] {
            {1.43,2,3},
            {3,4.34,5},
            {3,4,5}
    };
}
        // main function in assembler code
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 48   // <--- stack pointer is decresed
        mov     eax, 36
        mov     edi, eax
        call    operator new[](unsigned long)
        mov     rdi, rax
        // call ctors for vertex
```

the most important line from asm code is `sub rsp,48`. Now we change the size of array to have 6 vertices:

```
vertex* v = new vertex[6] {
        {1.43,2,3},
        // 4 lines here
        {3,4,5}
```

now compiler generates `sub rsp, 80` , as you can see the value subtracted from stack pointer is increased.

The greater vertices array, the more space is taken from stack. Stack is limited. And probably this is why your app crashes even if you allocate array onto heap. All memory of stack was used to initialize vertices of your array.

---

I compiled this code on https://godbolt.org/ with clang 6.0 selected without any optimizations. (Enabled optimizations changed much in output asm code). Of course other compilers may generate different code, instead of `sub rsp,BIG_VALUE` they can take the space of stack in portions for each ctor of vertex separately.

Comment: That makes sense to me and would explain why it literally doesn't matter whether I allocate memory for the array on the stack or the heap. But I yet fail to comprehend how to prevent the stack from being cluttered with vertex structs when initializing the array. Modifying the code as follows still seem to have the same effect: vertex* v = new vertex[6]; v[0] = vertex(1.43, 2, 3); v[1] = vertex(3, 4.34, 5); v[2] = vertex(3, 4, 5); ... Do you have any input on how to change the code to prevent that problem?

Comment: The easiest way for me is to move all doubles and bools into data segment, so you define two global arrays `double valD[] = {1,2,3}; bool valB[] = {true, false, true};`. Compiler puts all data of both arrays into data segment - it is safe. Then you allocate array on heap by `new`, and in one *for* loop call ctor for vertices with parameters for all elements of array `for (int i = 0; i < 25K; ++i){ a[i] = Vertex(valD[i],valD[i+1],..valB[i])}`.

Answer (score 1):

In embedded systems, the rule of thumb is to declare constants and large amounts of data as `static`:

```
static Vertex database[] = {/*...*/};
```

If your data is read-only, use the `const` keyword:

```
static const Vertex database[] = {/*...*/};
```

Check your compiler and linker documentation to see if you can create a memory segment for your data and how to assign the database to that memory segment.

Your compiler may impose restrictions on the above techniques, such as having to use only `struct` or that `Vertex` can't have any virtual methods.  Worst case, you'll have to use a 2d array:

```
static const double Vertices[MAXIMUM_ROWS][3] = {/*...*/};
```

By using `static const`, the compiler can place the data into a read-only data segment.  This allows for placing the data into read only memory devices, such as Flash or ROM (Yes, I know that Flash can be written into/programmed, but most of the time, it is treated as ROM).